# Systematic way to change values in stores

Tags: qwik

Current if I want to update the value of a store, I would do

```js
const store = useStore({ a: 100, b: 100 })
store.a = 200 // change the value by using store.xxx
store.b = 200
```

Is there a way I can pass a whole object without writing out the code manually?

```js
// For example, some magic function update
store.update({ a: 200, b:200 })
```

**EDIT:**

On closer look, **I don't think it is possible** since qwik's reactivity comes from subscription of proxy objects. If I were to use a function with objects passed in as props to "update" the store. The store will have no clue of what subscribers are there. However, I will leave the question open for further discussion.